# Perl WWW::Mechanize Credentials

Tags: perl

I want to search content from a site using WWW::Mechanize but to be able to do that first I must be logged in with my registered username and password, which I can't do with this code. What must be changed so I can submit the form successfully. Thanks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $username = "username";
my $password = "password";
my $cookie_jar;

my $url = "http://www.albumartexchange.com/forums/ucp.php?mode=login";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );

$mech->credentials($username, $password);
$mech->get($url);

$mech->success() or die "Failed";

$mech->submit_form(
   form_number => 4,
);
die "Submit failed" unless $mech->success;

$mech->save_content('log.txt');
```

UPDATE:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $cookie_jar;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );
$mech->get( 'http://www.albumartexchange.com/forums/ucp.php?mode=login' );

$mech->submit_form(
    form_number => 4,
    fields      => {
        'username'
            => 'some_username',
        'password'
            => 'some_password',
    }
);
$mech->save_content('log.txt');
```

Comment: By the way why you use $cookie_jar? Cookie stuff are enabled by default in the Mechanize so i'm sure you don't need to use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `credentials` here. Just use:

```
$mech->submit_form(
   form_number => 4,
   fields => {
        username => $user,
        password => $pass,
   },
);
```

Of course don't forget to change `username` and `password` to the actual field names for your target page.

Answer (score 0):

That page doesn't use HTTP authentication, which is what `credentials` is for. Just use Mech to fill in the `username` and `password` form fields and submit the login form.

Comment: Do you mean something like the update I posted because I still can't log in.