# How to authenticate when is not required using Perl?

Tags: perl, web-scraping, web-crawler

when trying to get access to a page that requires authentication with this code:

```
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent−>new;
my $url = 'http://www.unicode.org/mail−arch/unicode−ml/y2002−m08/0067.html';
my $response = $browser−>get($url);
```

an expected error is generated:

```
Error: Basic realm="Unicode−MailList−Archives"
       401 Authorization Required
       at http://www.unicode.org/mail−arch/unicode−ml/y2002−m08/0067.html
```

and this is taken care with:

```
$browser−>credentials(
 'www.unicode.org:80',
 'Unicode−MailList−Archives',
 'unicode−ml' => 'unicode'
);
```

But my problem is how to use authentication when it is optional but not required. For example if I want to enter to `http://www.coolstuffinc.com/user_main.php`, if im logged in it takes me to my user page and if I am not it takes me to the home page.
How can I do so it uses my credentials to enter to the user page.

Comment: Use [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) if you're navigating to more than one page and need to keep session information.  And use [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) if the webpages require JavaScript.

Comment: I am really new to perl and this topic in general (2 days new) so it will be helpful if you show me an example of WWW::Mechanize implementation

Comment: This question on logging in with WWW::Mechanize should be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701934/perl-wwwmechanize-credentials

Comment: More than likely the session is being managed through cookies; see http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch11_01.htm on how to save and send back login sessions to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

As always, do like you do if you were browsing: Navigate to the login form, fill it out, submit it, then visit the page you really want to visit.

Logging in will provide you with a cookie that will automatically be submitted in later requests. This is how the site knows who is logged in.